# Clarify how to specify file paths inside Docker coming from Python

Tags: python, docker, flask, filepath

I have created a Docker image with for a Flask app. Inside my Flask app, this is how I specify the file paths.

```
dPath = os.getcwd() + "\\data\\distanceMatrixv2.csv"
```

This should ideally resolve in a filepath similar to `app/data/distanceMatrixv2.csv`. This works when I do a `py main.py` run in the *CMD*. After making sure I am in the same directory, creating the image and running the Docker image via `docker run -it -d -p 5000:5000 flaskapp`, it throws me the error below when I try to do any processing.

```
FileNotFoundError: /backend\data\distanceMatrixv2.csv not found.
```

I believe this is due to how Docker resolves file paths but I am a bit lost on how to "fix" this. I am using **Windows** while my Docker image is built with `FROM node:lts-alpine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node:lts-alpine` is based on Alpine which is a Linux distro. So your python program runs under Linux and should use Linux file paths, i.e. forward slashes like

```
dPath = os.getcwd() + "/data/distanceMatrixv2.csv"
```

It looks like `os.getcwd()` returns `/backend`. So the full path becomes `/backend/data/distanceMatrixv2.csv`.

Comment: I ended up manually changing all the file paths in my `Python` file to use the `/` and it works. Another commentor mention using the `os.path` library but I skipped it for now.

Answer (score 1):

The [`os.path` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) can do this portably across operating systems.  If you write this as

```py
import os
import os.path

dPath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "data", "distanceMatrixv2.csv")
```

it will work whether your (Windows) system uses DOS-style backslash-separated paths or your (Linux) system uses Unix-style forward slashes.

Python 3.4 also added a [`pathlib` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), if you prefer a more object-oriented approach.  This redefines the Python `/` division operator to concatenate paths, using the native path separator.  So you could also write

```py
from pathlib import Path

dPath = Path.cwd() / "data" / "distanceMatrixv2.csv"
```